# Pathtracing Code is not working although i think i did it right

Tags: c#, bitmap

So i want to write a small pathtracer to get familiar with all the vector math and intersection calculations. So i created a Windows Forms Application in C# and use a PictureBox to display the bitmap.

Here is my class "renderScene". It creates the Bitmap, loops through every pixel, calculate a ray in dependence of the pixels. After creating a ray i trace it recursively through the world and finally return the color for the pixel.

```
public void renderScene()
    {
        Bitmap drawArea = new Bitmap(pB_Result.Size.Width, pB_Result.Size.Height);
        pB_Result.Image = drawArea;

        int height = pB_Result.Size.Height;
        int width = pB_Result.Size.Width;

        float fov = 160 * (float)Math.PI / 180;
        float zdir = 1.0f / (float)Math.Tan(fov);
        float aspect = (float)height / (float)width;

        //BWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new Tuple<int, int, Bitmap, float, float, float>(height, width, drawArea, fov, zdir, aspect));

        for (int y = 0; y < pB_Result.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < pB_Result.Width; x++)
            {
                float xdir = (x / (float)width) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
                float ydir = ((y / (float)height) * 2.0f - 1.0f) * aspect;
                Ray ray = new Ray(Camera, new Vector3D(xdir, ydir, zdir).normalize());

                float r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
                System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, RAYS_PER_PIXEL, i =>
                {
                    Color c = Trace(ray, 0);
                    r += c.R;
                    g += c.G;
                    b += c.B;
                });

                //for (int i = 0; i < RAYS_PER_PIXEL; i++)
                //{
                //    Color c = Trace(ray, 0);
                //    r += c.R;
                //    g += c.G;
                //    b += c.B;
                //}

                drawArea.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, (int)r / RAYS_PER_PIXEL, (int)g / RAYS_PER_PIXEL, (int)b / RAYS_PER_PIXEL));
            }
        }
        pB_Result.Image = drawArea;
    }
```

And here is my trace function which recursively intersects a ray with the scene:

```
public Color Trace(Ray ray, int depth, BaseObject missObject = null)
    {
        float distance = 5000.0f;
        BaseObject lastHitObject = null;
        Vector3D HitPoint = null;

        foreach (BaseObject obj in this.scene.Objects)
        {
            if (obj == missObject)
                continue;
            float currentDistance = obj.Intersect(ray);
            if (currentDistance < distance && currentDistance > 0)
            {
                distance = currentDistance;
                lastHitObject = obj;
            }
        }

        if (distance == 5000.0f) //Kein Objekt wurde getroffen
            return Color.Black;
        if (lastHitObject.isEmitter) //Eine Lichtquelle wurde getroffen
            return lastHitObject.surfaceColor;
        if (depth == MAX_DEPTH)
            return Color.Black;


        HitPoint = ray.origin.add(ray.direction.multiply(distance));
        Vector3D normal = lastHitObject.Normal(HitPoint);

        Ray reflectionRay = null;

        if (lastHitObject.mat == Material.Diffuse)
        {
            Vector3D randomVector = Vector3D.getRandomVectorInHemisphere();
            if (randomVector.Dotproduct(normal) < 0.0)
                randomVector = randomVector.negate();
            reflectionRay = new Ray(HitPoint, randomVector.normalize());
        }

        Color returnColor = Trace(reflectionRay, depth + 1, lastHitObject);

        float r = lastHitObject.surfaceColor.R * returnColor.R;
        float g = lastHitObject.surfaceColor.G * returnColor.G;
        float b = lastHitObject.surfaceColor.B * returnColor.B;

        r /= 255.0f;
        g /= 255.0f;
        b /= 255.0f;

        return Color.FromArgb(255, (int)r, (int)g, (int)b);
    }
```

I use the "missObject" parameter to avoid some float math inaccuracy so i don't check the last hit object again.

And here is my Vector3D class which represents a point in 3D Space. I also implemented a few functions to manipulate vectors:

```
    public class Vector3D
{
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
    public float z { get; set; }

    public Vector3D()
    { 

    }

    public Vector3D(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public float Dotproduct(Vector3D Dotvector)
    {
        return (Dotvector.x * this.x + Dotvector.y * this.y + Dotvector.z * this.z);
    }

    public float Length()
    {
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }

    public Vector3D subtract(Vector3D subVec)
    {
        return new Vector3D(this.x - subVec.x, this.y - subVec.y, this.z - subVec.z);
    }

    public Vector3D add(Vector3D addVec)
    {
        return new Vector3D(this.x + addVec.x, this.y + addVec.y, this.z + addVec.z);
    }

    public Vector3D add(float value)
    {
        return add(new Vector3D(value, value, value));
    }

    public Vector3D multiply(Vector3D multVec)
    {
        return new Vector3D(this.x * multVec.x, this.y * multVec.y, this.z * multVec.z);
    }

    public Vector3D multiply(float value)
    {
        return multiply(new Vector3D(value, value, value));
    }

    public Vector3D divide(Vector3D divVec)
    {
        return new Vector3D(this.x / divVec.x, this.y / divVec.y, this.z / divVec.z);
    }

    public Vector3D divide(float value)
    {
        return divide(new Vector3D(value, value, value));
    }

    public Vector3D CrossProduct(Vector3D crossVec)
    {
        return new Vector3D
        {
            x = this.y * crossVec.z - this.z * crossVec.y,
            y = this.z * crossVec.x - this.x * crossVec.z,
            z = this.x * crossVec.y - this.y * crossVec.x
        };
    }

    public Vector3D negate()
    {
        return new Vector3D
        {
            x = -x,
            y = -y,
            z = -z
        };
    }

    public Vector3D normalize()
    { 
        float f = (float)(1.0f / Math.Sqrt(this.Dotproduct(this)));

        x *= f;
        y *= f;
        z *= f;

        return new Vector3D(x, y, z);
    }

    public static Vector3D getRandomVectorInHemisphere()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        Vector3D v = new Vector3D
        {
            x = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * 2.0f - 1.0f,
            y = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * 2.0f - 1.0f,
            z = (float)rnd.NextDouble() * 2.0f - 1.0f
        };
        v = v.normalize();
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You need to make sure your question includes only the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the issue - i.e empty constructors are almost guaranteed to not have anything to do with your problem. Having saying that, you haven't actually said what the problem is exactly? what is your program currently doing that isn't expected?

Comment: Because i don't know what is exactly wrong i just posted everything i have. If i render a simple scene with 5 Spheres (1 emitter) i get this result: http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/studioray4imagwzndt723ql.png

Comment: Its a little hard to distinguish the exact problem at the minute (for me at least), it could be a case of floating precision (i.e your `fov` variable is divided by `180` instead of `180.0f`), I would say set breakpoints or write some stuff out to the console and see what is happening (you can change the output type to console application)

Comment: i printed the origin and the direction of the reflected rays and i always get two identical rays in a row. How does this happen?

New Ray [Origin: -0,4653343 -1,783782 0,4112778 | Direction: -0,7470875 0,4427105 0,4958506].
New Ray [Origin: -0,4653343 -1,783782 0,4112778 | Direction: -0,7470875 0,4427105 0,4958506].
New Ray [Origin: -0,4443789 -1,777516 0,4449596 | Direction: -0,7470875 0,4427105 0,4958506].
New Ray [Origin: -0,4443789 -1,777516 0,4449596 | Direction: -0,7470875 0,4427105 0,4958506].

Maybe because the Random generator generates the same numbers again? GetRandomVectorInHemisph

Comment: Yes its very possible that you are getting the same value from the random function (since it could be based off the same seed), you should declare the random outside of that method for a start which should reduce this risk

Comment: I declared rnd as public value in the Vector3D class. ITS LOOKING A LOT BETTER NOW THX!!! 
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/studioray5imag9m5rj08szk.png
But i don't know if it is correct
If i increase the RAYS_PER_PIXEL i get a worse image:
http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/studioray6imag3lrxa92ync.png

Comment: Not sure, sorry, could be integer division in your `SetPixel` (looks strange to me) but would just be a case of more debugging like you have been doing :) I would also recommend when you are happy that you add an answer to your own question with what fixed your issue so it may help future readers

Comment: Could it be that i have something wrong with my diffuse reflection technique (getRandomVectorInHemisphere)?

Comment: I don't understand it. At 1 Ray per Pixel i get a really good result in my opinion: http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/studioray7imag2bysc5ng1o.png BUT if i increase it just to 2 i get this: http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/studioray8imaguwnxhemaiv.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For, if i change it to a normal for loop i get a really good result:

http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/pathtracerv4i84onm23aiz.png